# Create shortcut to 'Play Selection' for Windows Media Player on Win7.

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, windows-media-player, selection

I have a directory with 40 video files. My current pattern is to select 10 of them at a time and click the 'Play Selection' button. This involves three clicks and has plenty of room for error:

1. Open the directory
2. Drag to select the files
3. Click 'Play selection' in the window header.

I'd like to set this up for other people to use. Can I create a windows shortcut that will play these 10 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following steps:

- Create your media selection (name it like you want) in Selections folder
- Click on the Video folder at the left then add your videos in your Selections folder
- Right-click on your video selection folder
- Choose "add to playlist" (normally a list appears at the right)
- Click on File item in the Menu & click on "Record your list" 
  (Use the keys CTRL+M to make appear the Menu in Windows Media Player)
- Record it where you want to save it (for example on the desktop)

The list will be with .wpl extension (if you enable file extensions) 
You can double-click on this file: it will launch your video selection.

WPL syntax explanations:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player_Playlist